# SQL Server and ASP.NET: Filter "Bit" DataType in SqlDataSource (FilterExpression) using DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, bit

I have `Gridview` which uses this `SqlDataSource` as `DataSource`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMetal" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:connStr%>"
        SelectCommand="select MetalName, MetalID, IsAvailable from Metal Where IsDeleted = 0" FilterExpression="IsAvailable like '%{0}%'>
   <asp:ControlParameter Name="IsAvailable" ControlID="ddlIsMetalAvailable" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Boolean" />
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And this is my DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIsMetalAvailable" DataValueField="IsAvailable"
     AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="150">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="True"  Value="True" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="False"  Value="False" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I am getting an error:

> *Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Boolean and System.String.*

I have also tried this filter expression but it doesn't helps me:

```
FilterExpression="Convert(IsAvailable, 'System.Boolean') like '%{0}%'
```

Comment: IsAvailable Is Bool field ?

Comment: ya its a BIT datatype of SQL SERVER

Comment: Then You Should Not Use Like Operator with Where Condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the error message - it clearly says what's wrong:

> *Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Boolean and System.String.*

You **cannot** use `LIKE` with a boolean value - you need to use an exact match.

So change your markup to be:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsMetal" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:connStr%>"
        SelectCommand="select MetalName, MetalID, IsAvailable from Metal Where IsDeleted = 0" 
        FilterExpression="IsAvailable = {0}'>   <=== HERE - use = {0} instead of LIKE
   <FilterParameters>
      <asp:ControlParameter Name="IsAvailable" ControlID="ddlIsMetalAvailable" 
                            PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Boolean" />
   </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

With this change, things should work just fine.